# What info other than the EDID is pulled from the display device?

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, xorg, hdmi

I'm trying to get a hardware recorder to work as the monitor for an Ubuntu 16.04 system (nvidia card/driver). If I boot the system with the HDMI plugged into my monitor everything works. I can then hotswap the HDMI to the recorder and it keeps the same settings and continues to work.

If I boot the system with the recorder plugged in, it hangs somewhere. There's no display, and I can't even SSH into the system.

I copied the monitor's EDID, and have configured X11 to use that file instead of loading from whatever's plugged in. I also have the modeline defined in xorg.conf. I don't know what else I can do to convince it to initialize as if the monitor is plugged in.

I also don't know if it's even getting as far as starting up X, since SSH isn't working so I don't have any information about what state/stage the startup process gets to.

Any suggestions?